# get the value from map using struts tags by passing another property as key

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2

```
<s:property value="currentStep" />
<s:set var="nextURL" value="%{campaignStepsMap.get(currentStep).nextUrl}" scope="page" />
<s:property value="nextURL" />
```

Here `currentStep` is a property having Integer value comming from action class. and `campaignStepMap` is a linkedHashMap. I want to get the value exactly similar in java with following code

```
campaignStepsMap.get(currentStep).nextUrl();
```

but here in Jsp page i'm not getting value corresponding to the index. Seems `value="%{campaignStepsMap.get(currentStep).nextUrl}"` is not reading `currentStep` as integer. What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value from map like that:

```
<s:property value="campaignStepsMap[currentStep].nextUrl"/>
```

And if you want to use `<s:set>` tag with `scope="page"` then you need to use `#attr` to get the value.

```
<s:set var="nextURL" value="campaignStepsMap[currentStep].nextUrl" scope="page"/>
<s:property value="#attr.nextURL"/>
```

Comment: I don't know why this way cannot work. And my way is `<s:property value="%{#request. campaignStepsMap[currentStep].nextUrl}"/>`, I refered this page https://dzone.com/articles/struts-2-creating-and

Comment: @zhuguowei: What do you mean? OP has `scope="page"`.